# Two Html.EnumDropdownListFor instruction for 2 enum properties of a model, one works not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 enum properties in a model in asp.net MVC application. Both of these properties are displayed and edit in a View using @HTML.EnumDropdownForList, one enum property (Model.CurrentStatus) displays correctly but other didn't (Model.Title). I can't work out why this behaviour. Can any one see what the problem is?

Enums:

```
public enum Status : int
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Active = 1,
        Deactivated = 2,
        MembershipPaymentPending = 3,
        NewlyRegistered = 4,
        RenewalPending = 5,
    }

 public enum Titles : int
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Mr = 1,
        Mrs = 2,
        Ms = 3,
        Miss = 4,
        Dr = 5
    }
```

Model.CurrentStatus = Deactivate (displayed correctly)

Model.Title = Mr (displayed incorrectly)

cshtml:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Title, "--- Select ---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 300px; height: 35px; " } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

       
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentStatus, "--- Select ---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

}
```

Comment: I’d recommend removing all of the unrelated razor markup that’s not relevant to your immediate question so that readers don’t need to hunt through your code to find the different instances of `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()`. It’s best to keep your questions focused on the most relevant code.

Comment: It would be helpful to share more relevant details or (even better) modify your repro code to make those details obvious. For example: what do these properties look like on your model? Are you sure you've namespaced things correctly so you're not using the wrong enum type for `Titles`? What do you mean by "displays incorrectly"? "Mr" looks correct to me: are you saying that's not the value of the Title? If so, how did you verify that Title hasn't been set to "Mr"?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question. The property is call Title of type Titles in a class, although the property has value of ‘Mr’ it still displaying’—- select —-‘ and I have checked the value to be ‘Mr’

Comment: Hi all. I have managed to ‘resolve’ this issue myself by renaming the property from Title to TitleGiven. All works fine. I don’t know why, if anyone can explain it, I love to know the reason. Thank you for your time.